# Conditioning LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

Currently I have a LINQ query like this:

```
var policy = snapshotDate == null
                ? await _dbContext.VPolicies
                        .Where(p => p.PolicyNumber.Trim().Equals(policyNumber))
                        .OrderByDescending(d => d.PolicyEffectiveDate)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                : await _dbContext.VPolicies
                        .Where(p => p.PolicyNumber.Trim().Equals(policyNumber)
                                    && (p.PolicyEffectiveDate <= snapshotDate && p.PolicyExpirationDate > snapshotDate))
                        .OrderByDescending(d => d.PolicyEffectiveDate)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I would like to know if I can shorten it like this:

```
        var policy = await _dbContext.VPolicies
                                .Where(p => p.PolicyNumber.Trim().Equals(policyNumber))
                                .Where(p => snapshotDate != null && (p.PolicyEffectiveDate <= snapshotDate && p.PolicyExpirationDate > snapshotDate))
                                .OrderByDescending(d => d.PolicyEffectiveDate)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But this doesn't work and I would like to know how I can condition this LINQ query in a proper way and shorten them without using the terenary operator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: Well the first LINQ query gets me all the results when i don't provide a snapshot date. the second linq query gives me null when i don't provide a snapshot date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var policy = await _dbContext.VPolicies
                                .Where(p => p.PolicyNumber.Trim().Equals(policyNumber)
                                 && (snapshotDate == null ||
                                 (p.PolicyEffectiveDate <= snapshotDate && 
                                  p.PolicyExpirationDate > snapshotDate)))
                                 .OrderByDescending(d => d.PolicyEffectiveDate)
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This query will apply conditions of PolicyEffectiveDate and PolicyExpirationDate if snapshotDate is not null otherwise only PolicyNumber condition will apply.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want your *condition* to evaluate

```
snapshotDate == null || (p.PolicyEffectiveDate <= snapshotDate && p.PolicyExpirationDate > snapshotDate)
```

Which says, give all dates when `snapshotDate` is null, or *within* when it's not.

<sub>***Note** : about multiple `where` clauses. In a memory based collection you are will get a performance increase combining them with an `&&` (due to the extra delegate invocation, and potential multiple enumerations), however with most LINQ to Query providers it will evaluate in the exact same SQL. Though in general it's best combining these if you can*.</sub>